# How to get Unix Local Time?

Tags: date, date-time, timestamp, timezones

I have a given time and I'd like to confirm that is AFTER the current time.

```
$expires_epoch = strtotime($_POST['expiry']);
if($expires_epoch < current_time('mysql')){
...do stuff...
```

This snippet only works if I set my server to match my local time. That is to say that it's working in UTC time. Any ideas on what to fix? I've tried many alternative to `current_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `DateTime::getTimestamp()` that returns unix timestamp.

If you want to format the date according to your time zone then you try this.

```
$datetime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New York'));

echo $datetime ->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```